# How to Parse string of the format 04 Nov 2018 07:39 AM

Tags: r, date, lubridate

I have data imported from an external report which contains a column of dates in the following format : 04 Nov 2018 07:39 AM
I would like to parse that string into a date but am unable to find an orders string that can handle that format

```
library(lubridate)
Vec1 <- ("04 Nov 2018 07:39 AM")
parse_date_time(Vec1, orders = 'dmy')
```

[1] NA
Warning message:
All formats failed to parse. No formats found.

Comment: Almost there:  lubridate::dmy_hm("04 Nov 2018 07:39 AM") ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read `?strptime`

```
Vec1 <- ("04 Nov 2018 07:39 AM")
as.POSIXct(Vec1, format = "%d %b %Y %H:%M %p")
#[1] "2018-11-04 07:39:00 GMT"
```

---

With `lubridate` you actually needed the hour and minute component

```
library(lubridate)
parse_date_time(Vec1, orders = "dmyhm")
```

Or as @ed_sans mentioned

```
dmy_hm(Vec1)
```